# A simple jquery dropdown box when clicked

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I can't find the one I want anywhere, yet it's really simple.  All I want is a simple jQuery script that when I click on a link, it pops a small div out (over the top of the current page, not hiding a DIV and sliding it in).

If I've not explained it very well, best think to look at is the notifications popout on Facebook, that's basically what I want.

This is also a good example, except it doesn't seem to work properly when I download the code from here: http://www.awmcreative.com/blog/jquery/jquery-pop-menu/#more-713

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

Doesn't matter if it retracts by clicking again, or by moving mouse out of the area.

Cheers.

Comment: Wait, is this question a "how do I make it" question or "fix it for me" question? In the latter case, what's not working? In the former, you provided a tutorial.

Comment: It's a "I'm looking for a different one"

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) has this functionality built in.

Comment: how is that what the OP wants??

Comment: he asked for a popup, he got a popup

Comment: see link in question and new title